# setState no se actualiza con react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Amig@s, estoy tratando de implementar **[react-hook-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form)** a mi aplicación pero estoy teniendo un inconveniente al querer actualizar el `state`, ya que al momento de dar *click* en el `submit` los valores de los inputs efectivamente llegan a la function, pero cuando trato de pasar esos valores a un `const [values, setValues] = useState({})` este no se actualiza, y más extraño aun es que si vuelvo a hacer click en el submit si lo hace como debería.

Les adjunto el código y el **[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-morning-l2e5v?file=/src/App.js)** para que puedan replicarlo

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});

  const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(`before set -> ${JSON.stringify(values)}`);
    setValues(data);
    console.log(`after set -> ${JSON.stringify(values)}`);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="user"
          ref={register({
            required: { value: true, message: "El campo no puede estar vacio" }
          })}
        />
        <span>{errors?.user?.message}</span>
        <br />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="pass"
          ref={register({
            required: { value: true, message: "El campo no puede estar vacio" }
          })}
        />
        <span>{errors?.pass?.message}</span>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Ignoro si estoy abordando mal el problema o al utilizar este package, la forma de trabajar con `hooks` cambia un poco.

Como siempre, cualquier orientación la agradezco!

Comment: Lo qué pasa es que en el primer click que das el estado values está vacío, es por eso que tus console.log imprimen vacío. El seValues lo hace bien, inserta los valores que ingresas en los inputs, y es por eso que en el segundo click ya se muestran los valores. Lo puedes mirar mejor si rendereas el valor de values dentro de span.

Comment: Disculpa la demora, y gracias por responder. Al parecer no fui tan claro como esperaba, ya que lo que tú me mencionas y me explicas sé porque es.. mi problema es que porque al momento de imprimir mi constante despues de setear los valores me sigue imprimiendo vacío siendo que mi función es asincrona

Comment: metele un useEffect a values y hacele un console.log el setstate puede que tenga una milidemora que tarda en entrar y probablemente te esta imprimiendo el console.log antes de tener los datos seteados